# FN lock is always enabled upon boot, how to make it defualt to "off"?

Tags: boot, function-keys

The title says it all. Whenever I boot up, fn lock is enabled, so I have to disable it manually by pressing fn+esc. I've done lots of searching online and I'm sure this has been answered somewhere, but search results (and there are TONS) are all related to other fn lock issues. I'm wondering if there is a way to have it default to off, just to save the annoyance of needing to remember to manually turn it off every time I boot up.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 (currently using Linux kernel 5.8, but the problem also exists in Kernel 5.4) on an Asus Zenbook UX434IQ, model Q407IQ. The same issue did not occur in Windows 10

Thanks so much for any help!